# Incorrect comment syntax applied to an HTML file when using the shortcut in VSCode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

When I tried to comment in HTML file using `CTRL + /` in VSCode it displayed:

```
{% comment %}This is a comment{% endcomment %}
```

instead of:

```
<!-- This is a comment -->
```

Is there a way to encourage VSCode to apply the correct syntax?

Comment: Sounds like you need to change the language to HTML. Sounds like it is currently set to some template language.

Comment: @Quentin  Oh yes .. it was set to a Django extension.. it works perfectly after I have disabled it.. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

try using ctrl+K+C

you can use this shortcut in every language inside vscode. i belive this is the default shortcut for making line comments, even multiline comments.

edit: as per vscode, ctrl+/ is for toggling the comment. if you need to check it proper. try **ctrl+shift+P** > type **keyboard shortcuts**. you can find something like "**preferences: open keyboard shortcuts**". go for it and open.

from that window search for comment. you can find all the shortcuts related to comment are listed. be careful if you are making changes in there. its going to be permanent.